# Unexpected } - but nothing to close

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I do hope my question fits here, because I read the FAQ but it isn't clear to me whether I should run code errors here. Anyway, this snippet (extracted from a project I work on) is giving me a hard time. When checking in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/CJSpg/) it tells me that it expected `}` for closing the `animate({` but instead found `300`, but that doesn't make sense because there is nothing to match, animate is already closed.

Console then, tells me that the comma before `300` was unexpected. I really don't understand the problem with it!

```
var condition = offL > ((wW / 2) - $this.width()),
  propertiesAnim = [],
  propertiesCss = [];

if (condtion) {
  properties = "'left': offL - tooltip.width() - 25";
  propertiesCss = "'right', 'auto'";
} else {
  properties = "'right': offR - tooltip.width() - 25";
  propertiesCss = "'left', 'auto'";
}

tooltip.stop(true).css(propertiesCss).text(title).animate({
  "top": ($this.offset().top + (posT / 2) - (tooltip.height() / 2)),
  properties
}, 300).fadeTo(200, 1); // Error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can neither add to a "property" list nor insert variables into strings like that.

Firstly, use correct object literal syntax to fill your properties (which need to be declared as objects, not arrays)

```
var properties = {}, css = {};

if (condtion) {
    properties = { left: offL - tooltip.width() - 25 };
    css = { right: 'auto' };
} else {
    properties = { right: offR - tooltip.width() - 25 };
    css = { left: 'auto' };
}
```

and then, use `$.extend` to add new properties to an existing object, or just add the required value directly, i.e.

```
$.extend(properties, {
    top: $this.offset().top + (posT / 2) - (tooltip.height() / 2)
});
```

or:

```
properties.top = $this.offset().top + (posT / 2) - (tooltip.height() / 2);
```

then:

```
...animate(properties);
```

`$.extend()` is preferred if you already have one set of object properties and want to merge the contents of another.  For just adding one property the latter method is simpler.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I altered your solution a bit and it works great. I wouldn't use `css` as object though. Don't know if it works or not, but it might be confusing!

Answer (score 4):

There is no key specified for the value in `properties`. Correct syntax (from the strictly theoretical point of view) would be:

```
tooltip.stop(true).css(propertiesCss).text(title).animate({
  "top": (...),
  "someKey": properties
}, 300);
```

Of course this will not produce the expected result because, while syntactically valid, it's meaningless from jQuery's point of view. To make things work you can use [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/):

```
// conditional properties
if (condition) {
  properties = { "left": offL - tooltip.width() - 25 };
} else {
  properties = { "right": offR - tooltip.width() - 25 };
}

// merging the above with default properties
$.extend(properties, {
    "top": (...),
});

tooltip.stop(true).css(propertiesCss).text(title).animate(properties, 300);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a string variable as part of the syntax in an object literal. The Javascript engine expects a colon and a value after `properties`. It doesn't see it as the variable, it sees it as an identifier for a property in the object.

Similarly, you can't use a string containing two values instead of two properties when calling a function. The `css` function can however take an object instead of two parameters.

Create the object before the `if` statement, so that you can set properties in it:

```
var condition = offL > ((wW / 2) - $this.width()),
  propertiesCss,
  properties = {
    "top": ($this.offset().top + (posT / 2) - (tooltip.height() / 2))
  };

if (condtion) {
  properties.left = offL - tooltip.width() - 25;
  propertiesCss = { right: 'auto' };
} else {
  properties.right = offR - tooltip.width() - 25;
  propertiesCss = { left: 'auto' };
}

tooltip.stop(true).css(propertiesCss).text(title).animate(properties, 300).fadeTo(200, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

For something very different, you might consider this approach :

```
var propertiesCss = {},
    propertiesAnim = {
        "top": ($this.offset().top + (posT / 2) - (tooltip.height() / 2))
    },
    i = 0 + (offL > ((wW / 2) - $this.width())),//0 or 1
    ii = -(i-1),//1 or 0
    sides = ['left', 'right'],
    off = [offL : offR];

propertiesAnim[sides[i]] = off[i] - tooltip.width() - 25);
propertiesCss[sides[ii]] = 'auto';

tooltip.stop(true).css(propertiesCss).text(title).animate(propertiesAnim, 300).fadeTo(200, 1);
```

This is more of a "mathematician's" approach, applicable when you need to choose from many variants of basic equation(s). In such situations, the pattern is economical of code, (though not of memory), and can provide for good extendability.

Comment: +1 for creativity, but this exceeds my knowledge of understanding, so it would not be efficient for me to use (for future reference).

Comment: Bram, one day you will get to the point where you realize the above code is actually very simple. Good luck.

Comment: I hope I will, but I have never seen any guide on using vars such as `i`. I hope to find one soon.